# Where can I find some open DB with linguistic ontologies?

Tags: nlp, ontology, linguistics

Are there any open DB with lingustic ontology?
I need some example of built ontology for reserch (ontology of some text or some subject area). These ontologies will be used as standard.

Maybe there are some DB with manually built ontologies and build using some tools.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[BabelNet](http://babelnet.org/)

> BabelNet is a multilingual lexicalized semantic network and ontology
>   developed at the Linguistic Computing Laboratory in the Department of
>   Computer Science of the Sapienza University of Rome. BabelNet
>   was automatically created by linking the largest multilingual Web
>   encyclopedia, Wikipedia, to the most popular computational lexicon of
>   the English language, WordNet. The integration is performed by means
>   of an automatic mapping and by filling in lexical gaps in
>   resource-poor languages with the aid of statistical machine
>   translation. The result is an "encyclopedic dictionary" that provides
>   concepts and named entities lexicalized in many languages and
>   connected with large amounts of semantic relations.

Comment: As far as I understood, the result "encyclopedic dictionary" in only available? Or we can get some ontology graphs (or some other data) in some subject area? The question appeared, because I want to compare my test method of creating ontology from text with some standard. Thanks anyway for response:)

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question, could you explain better?

Answer (score 0):

WordNet has an ontology - I've never used it, but you can find it at:
http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/ontology